# How to generate rdoc for a gem in an rvm gemset?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am using rvm and  the `rb-gsl` gem. I have created a gemset with rvm `2.7.3@my_app`. I have a global option to not generate rdoc documentation.  If I run

```
gem server --dir=gempath/ruby-2.7.3@my_app
```

I can view my the rb-gsl gems at `http://0.0.0.0:8808`. But I cannot click on the rdoc link because there is is no documentation generated for that gem.  How do I do generate the documentation for the gem so it is in 2.7.3@my_app?

Comment: What if you just use `gem rdoc rb-dsl --no-ri`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate docs directly with the `gem` command:

```
gem rdoc rb-gsl --no-ri
```

The `--no-ri` switch skips the generation of `ri` documentation (the command line tool to fetch gem docs). It saves a little bit of disk space if you are not using `ri`. Otherwise you can remove it and it will generate both RI and RDoc documentation at the same time.